# "Ruf mich bei deinem Namen"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, preposition, vocabulary

Es gibt einen Film, der heißt "call me by your name" (2017), ins Deutsche wurde er als "Ruf mich bei deinem Namen" übersetzt.

Ich tue mich schwer, die Präposition "bei" bei der deutschen Übersetzung als richtig zu verstehen, denn im Englischen trägt die Präposition "by" auch die Bedeutung von "using", so dass der Satz als "call me using your name" verstanden werden könnte, allerdings eine solche gewisse Bedeutung der deutschen Präposition kenne ich nicht, und auch im Duden konnte ich keine ähnliche Bedeutung finden.

Ist es nur so übersetzt, weil die Präposition "bei" die parallele für das englische "by" ist, oder ist es wirklich korrekt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bei* ist die einzig korrekte Präposition und sie wird auch deutlich später als in der Bibel verwendet, beispielsweise in Kafkas *Amerika*
:

> Jetzt blieb keine Hilfe als die Quergasse, und als er gar aus dieser Gasse ganz harmlos **beim Namen gerufen wurde** – es schien ihm zwar zuerst eine Täuschung zu sein, denn ein Sausen hatte er schon die ganze Zeit lang in den Ohren –, zögerte er nicht mehr länger und bog, um die Polizeileute möglichst zu überraschen, auf einem Fuß sich schwenkend, rechtwinklig in diese Gasse ein.

Tatsächlich ist die Verwendung von räumlichen Präpositionen für vergleichbare Angaben eher die Regel als die Ausnahme:

- Das Buch erschien **unter dem Pseudonym** xy.
- "Sie erreichen mich telefonisch **unter der Nummer** ..."
- "Preisvergleiche der diversen Internet-by-Call-Anbieter nebst weiteren übersichtlichen Informationen bietet das Internet mittlerweile **unter Adressen** wie www.billiger..."
- Schriftliche Vorschläge sammelt die Bahn **unter der Anschrift**: Bahnhofsname, 10484 Berlin

Answer (score 6):

Die Formulierung

> jemand *bei* seinem Namen rufen/ nennen

wird verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass man einen festgelegten Namen für jemand gebraucht (vgl. etwa [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/rufen) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rufen#d-1-4), jeweils Bedeutung 4 des Stichworts *rufen*). Das DWDS nennt in seiner Definition das Beispiel:

> jmdn. *bei* seinem Spitznamen rufen

Weitere Belege kann man durch die Suche in den verschiedenen Textkorpora finden.

Die Präposition *bei* ist hier also richtig. Tatsächlich wüsste ich nicht, womit man sie ersetzen könnte, dass es trotzdem noch richtig klingt. Falsch fände ich zumindest die Präposition *mithilfe* analog zu *using* im Englischen. Das würde nämlich implizieren, dass der Name eine Art Werkzeug oder Hilfsmittel wäre, der bzw. das das Rufen ermöglicht.

Comment: Ich fand den Hinweis (und Nachweis), dass die Präposition "bei" weiterhin auch heute so genutzt wird, zum Beispiel in "bei seinem Spitznamen nennen", hier schon sehr wichtig, denn in meiner Antwort stand das zunächst nicht so klar drin.

Answer (score 5):

Der Film geht auf einen Roman gleichen Titels zurück, der deutsche Filmtitel ist auch der Titel des auf Deutsch übersetzten Romans.

Der Ausdruck, um den es geht, kommt so in der Lutherbibel vor:

> "Und nun spricht der Herr[...]: ich habe dich bei deinem Namen gerufen; du bist mein!" (Jes 43,1)

> "Um Jakobs, meines Knechts, und um Israels, meines Auserwählten, willen rief ich dich bei deinem Namen und gab dir Ehrennamen, obgleich du mich nicht kanntest." (Jes 45,4)

Der Titel des Originalromans ist vermutlich auch (direkt oder indirekt) ein Bezug auf die erste Stelle und wurde deshalb m.E. auch zu Recht so übersetzt wie in der Lutherbibel.

Dass der Ausdruck "jemanden bei seinem Namen rufen" für heutige Ohren außergewöhnlich (weil altertümlich) klingt, ist für einen Roman- oder Filmtitel ein Pluspunkt. Gerade bei Buchtiteln ist es ja üblich, zu versuchen, durch ungewohnte Formulierungen aufzufallen und Neugier zu wecken.

Die Präposition "bei" ist heute noch im Ausdruck "etwas/jemanden beim Namen nennen" oder "etwas/jemanden bei seinem Namen nennen" üblich.

Comment: Das heißt, die Proposition "bei" hatte früher eine andere/zusätzliche Bedeutung? Welche genau war es wenn ja?

Comment: "durch ungewohnte Formulierungen aufzufallen und Neugier zu wecken" - als überhaupt nicht bibelfester Mensch muss ich sagen, dass ich als erstes an einen Übersetzer mangelhafter Qualität gedacht hatte. Der historische Hintergrund erklärt es, aber eben dass der Ausdruck heutzutage altertümlich klingt, ließ mich zunächst davon ausgehen, dass hier ein unfähiger Übersetzer "to call" allzu wörtlich als "rufen" übersetzt haben könnte, statt die (auch heutzutage!) viel gebräuchlichere Formulierung "Nenn mich bei meinem Namen" zu wählen. (Fürs Protokoll: *Neugier* hätte das bei mir nicht geweckt ;) )

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: naja, sooo ungewöhnlich ist "jemanden bei seinem Namen rufen" dann wieder auch nicht. Grundsätzlich sind viele Formulierungen aus der Lutherbibel bei vielen Leuten im erweiterten Sprachgefühl irgendwo noch enthalten, auch weil es in der Literatur oder der aktuellen Sprache immer wieder Bezüge darauf gibt.

Comment: @sermonionx "bei" und "by" haben gemeinsamen germanischen Urspring (und bedeuteten logischerweise auch mal dasselbe, siehe auch niederländisches "bij").

Comment: @HalvarF: Die These, dass "jemanden bei seinem Namen rufen" an sich ungewöhnlich ist, stammt ja gar nicht von mir; die habe ich direkt aus deiner Antwort übernommen. Ich wollte aber über den Punkt nicht diskutieren, da mir "jemanden bei seinem Namen nennen" in der Tat als gebräuchlicher erscheint als "jemanden bei seinem Namen rufen". (Dadurch bleibt aber festzuhalten, dass es eher gar nicht ums "bei" an sich geht, sondern, wenn überhaupt, speziell um die Kombination "rufen + bei".)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Was ich sagen wollte: die Formulierung ist heute ungewöhnlich, aber nicht so sehr, dass ich glaube, dass viele Leute eine schlechte Übersetzung annehmen würden.

Comment: I think the point is that the *English title* refers to the bible: "But now thus saith the LORD that created thee, O Jacob, and he that formed thee, O Israel: Fear not, for I have redeemed thee; I have called thee by thy name, thou art mine." See https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueFilm/comments/7an5di/biblical_allusions_in_call_me_by_your_name/. And thus it is completely adequate to translate it in biblical style.

Comment: @HalvarF: Ok - und worauf ich hinauswollte, war, dass man "Call me by your name" rein sprachlich sowohl mit "Ruf mich bei meinem Namen" als auch mit "Nenn mich bei meinem Namen" übersetzen könnte. Dabei ist Letzteres im heutigen Sprachgebrauch meinem Eindruck nach deutlich gebräuchlicher als Ersteres, während "to call" bei manchen deutschen Muttersprachlern vorrangig mit "(an/auf)rufen" in Verbindung gebracht werden dürfte. Damit ist bei Vorkommen von "ruf ... bei" eine unbeholfene Übersetzung naheliegend, zumal mir der hier zutreffende biblische Kontext unbekannt war.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper wenn schon, dann "ruf' mich bei **deinem** Namen". Ob "nennen" im Deutschen allerdings mit "bei" zusammengeht - dafür habe ich keinen Beleg. "rufen" funktioniert lt. H. Luther.

Comment: @tofro: Man kann die Dinge schon beim Namen nennen und sagen, dass "beim Namen nennen" absolut alltäglich ist.

Comment: Vielleicht stehe ich ja auf dem Schlauch, aber wie wird aus "ruf Dich bei Deinem Namen" ein "ruf mich bei Deinem Namen"? Merkwürdig, dass sich niemand daran stört.

Comment: @userunknown Wer den Roman liest (oder den Film sieht), merkt, dass das eigentlich Ungewöhnliche am Titel ist, dass „mein“ und „dein“ vertauscht sind. Die zwei Protagonisten tauschen ihre Namen. (Normalerweise würde es ja heissen „ruf mich bei meinem Namen“.)

Comment: @wra: Ah, danke. Ich kenne weder Buch noch Film aber so ist dieser merkwürdige Aspekt des Satzes für mcih dann geklärt.